# Reading multiple CSVs separately and saving them into a dictionary of dataframes in parallel in Python

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask

I have a Python function (shown below) that reads in multiple csv files from S3 and saves them separately as Pandas DataFrames in a dictionary. Is there a way to parallelize this process so that multiple items in `tables` can be read simultaneously instead of one-by-one?

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Define function    
def read_data(bucket_name, tables):
    all_data = dict()
    for t in tables:
        all_data[t] = dd.read_csv('s3://{}/{}/*.csv'.format(bucket_name, t)).compute()
    return all_data

# Define arguments
bucket_name = 's3://my-bucket'
tables = ['sales', 'customers', 'inventory']

# Run function
all_data = read_data(bucket_name, tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

Except using map functions i don't see how you could optimize it better. If you are trying to do one API call to your bucket there might a search parameter to that endpoint on AWS API?